# XSLT Function that creates a unique reference string for each TEI element

Tags: xslt, tei

I have a  in TEI with multiple  elements.
Basically I want to transform the list from this

```
<listEvent>
<event> <!--other stuff here--> </event>
<event> <!--other stuff here--> </event>
<event> <!--other stuff here--> </event>
</listEvent>
```

to

```
<listEvent>
<event ana="event1"> <!--other stuff here--> </event>
<event ana="event2"> <!--other stuff here--> </event>
<event ana="event3"> <!--other stuff here--> </event>
</listEvent>
```

and so on. So every  is supposed to have a @ana Attribute with a unique value.

i don't know how to do this.

Comment: Use the `generate-id()` function.